# Is it possible to Click a label control on WPF/WinForm App using Microsoft Automation UI

Tags: c#, wpf, microsoft-ui-automation

On our application we have a clickable label which will pop up another window. I have been reading through the Microsoft Automation UI documentation, and can't find a way in which I'm able to click a label control.

I know that I can't use the Invoke Pattern as this only deals with Button controls.

Below is the code from the XAML that we have

```
 <Label Name="LblCompleteOrdersCount" Content="{Binding CompleteOrders, Mode=OneWay}" Margin="434,45,0,0" Height="62" Width="170" Padding="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" FontSize="56" FontWeight="Bold">
    <Label.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Command="{Binding Path=CompleteOrdersCommand}" MouseAction="LeftClick" />
    </Label.InputBindings>
 </Label>
```

Comment: What made you pick Label instead of Button? Any special functionality weights in favour of Label?

Comment: @Maximus The Label is used to show the number of complete orders that we have. Our business needed a way in which they could easily see the number of complete orders (and a summary of each) so they could export these orders to an excel sheet.

Comment: And Button is not capable of this?

Comment: @Maximus We could put a button in however we need the label to show the number of orders completed.

Comment: Use then Button, override default Template and make it look like Label. I see no point in messing around if Label provides nothing more than Button but it lacks from UI Testing support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My hint is to use **Button**. It derives from *ICommandSource* interface and therefore you can effortlessly use Command to associate Button with handler. Ask yourself: what functionality does a Label provide that a Button does not? Better look? Override default Button's Template and you will get equivalent look. As long as you do not take advantage of any additional functionality of Label I see no point is messing around with it.

Comment: This is not an answer for running/deployed apps where changing the design is out of scope at the moment.

Answer (score 5):

You got 3 options to solve this problem from my point of view:

1. **UI Automation approach** is to **override the AutomationPeer** of your component and return a ButtonAutomationPeer in your case. The big advantage here is beeing able to model every custom behaviour required. [Microsoft's docu](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj219211) for further reading
2. Use the **ClickablePoint** of your Label, and **combine** it with **User32.dll** (to fire the actual mouseclick on the provided coordinates).  - see also microsoft [mouse_event function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-mouse_event?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
   docu for further details - This solution does not require any changes in your app but faces the following drawback: you won't be able to automate several apps simultaneously, if you don't build proper sub-routines on your own and you have to take care to keep the Application in the foreground (you may use the [ShowWindow function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow?redirectedfrom=MSDN) from User32.dll for that).
3. As already suggested by Maximus **use a Button and make it look like a Label**. I agree with him, that it should be a valid workaround in our case.

Comment: Option (1) is supposed to work in WPF only ? Can you give or point to an example of option (2) ?

Comment: Hi, regarding (1) I only used this for WPF, not sure what to do for winforms -> add new SO question? regarding (2) I am sorry, all those years I referred to the wrong .dll name,edited my post and added a microsoft docu link for you regarding the relevant function..